# Unable to run any code in code blocks,says permission is denied

Tags: 16.04, code-blocks

Unable to run any code in code blocks

says permission is denied

screen-shot of error message displayed

[image: Link to the screenshot of error message displayed.]

Comment: Have you set the permissions of the file?(chmod 777 FILE)

Comment: You can't **Run** C source code directly - you need to **Build** it into a binary executable first

Comment: No i haven't,please explain me in detail as i'm new to ubuntu and in windows it worked perfectly and i need to learn "C"and codeblocks is best for it.@ADDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You just open a new file using ( Ctrl + Shift + N )

Than save it using ( Ctrl + S )

Than name it. And after the name Just put (.c)
```

Comment: Thanks.@tso,it was already saving the files as c\c++,therefore i didn't care to put ".c" extension after the name of file.Now i tried it and it worked!